# django forms.py widgets cannot render in template (UpdateView)

Tags: django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I got the a problem, widgets in forms.py cannot render in template.
I want to create edit form in my application and i try used widgets in forms.py, but the widgets cannot render in template.
Any solutions ?

Form in html render like this, (class, placeholder, etc not rendering) :
[IMAGE FORM EDIT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HnVZ.png)

**forms.py**

```
class UserUsulanUpdatePenelitianForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model           = UserUsulan
    exclude         = ['status_usulan' ,'jumlah_dana_disetujui', 'keterangan_operator', 'com_reviewer_1', 'com_reviewer_2' ]
    widget = {
        'anggota'                   : Select2MultipleWidget({'class' : 'form-control select2-multi', 'multiple' : 'multiple', 'name' : 'tags' }),
        'tmt_awal'                  : forms.TextInput({'class' : 'form-control',  'placeholder' : 'TMT Awal', 'type' : 'date'}),
        'tmt_akhir'                 : forms.TextInput({'class' : 'form-control',  'placeholder' : 'TMT Akhir', 'type' : 'date'}),
        'judul_penelitian'          : forms.Textarea({'class' : 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'Judul Penelitian', 'rows':3, 'cols':20}),
    }
```

**views.py**

```
class UserUsulanPenelitianUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
template_name       = 'dashboard/usulan-penelitian-edit.html'
form_class          = UserUsulanUpdatePenelitianForm
queryset            = UserUsulan.objects.all()
context_object_name = 'listUsulanPenelitian'

def form_valid(self, form):
    messages.success(self.request, 'Usulan Penelitian Telah Diedit!')
    return super().form_valid(form)

def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse('dashboard:usulan-penelitian')
```

**usulan-penelitian-edit.html**

```
<form method="post">
                {% csrf_token%}
                {{form.errors}}
                <div class="inputbox mt-3"> {{form.ketua}} <span>Ketua Penelitian</span> </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="inputbox mt-3 mr-2"> {{form.anggota}} <i class="fa fa-users"></i> <span>Anggota</span> </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="d-flex flex-row">
                            <div class="inputbox mt-3 mr-2"> {{form.tmt_awal}} <span>TMT Awal</span> </div>
                            <div class="inputbox mt-3 mr-2"> {{form.tmt_akhir}} <span>TMT Akhir</span> </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="mt-4 mb-4">
                    <h6 class="text-uppercase">Detail Penelitian</h6>
                    <div class="row mt-3">
                      <div class="inputbox mt-3"> {{form.judul_penelitian}} <span>Judul Penelitian</span> </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="inputbox mt-3 mr-2"> {{form.tahun}} <span>Tahun</span> </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="inputbox mt-3 mr-2"> {{form.jenis_penelitian}} <span>Jenis</span> </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="inputbox mt-3 mr-2"> {{form.bidang_penelitian}} <span>Bidang</span> </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row mt-2">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="inputbox mt-3 mr-2"> {{form.skema_penelitian}} <span>Skema</span> </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="inputbox mt-3 mr-2"> {{form.target_luaran}} <span>Target</span> </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row mt-2">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="inputbox mt-3 mr-2"> {{form.tujuan_sosial_ekonomi}} <span>Tujuan Sosial Ekonomi</span> </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="mt-4 mb-4">
                    <h6 class="text-uppercase">Dana Penelitian</h6>
                    <div class="row mt-3">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="inputbox mt-3 mr-2"> {{form.jumlah_dana_usulan}} <span>Dana Usulan</span> </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" name="simpan" id="simpan" class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block" value="Simpan"/>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

the widgets cannot render because typo in write code widget. The Correct code is **widgets** not **widget**

**before**

```
widget = {
    'anggota'                   : Select2MultipleWidget({'class' : 'form-control select2-multi', 'multiple' : 'multiple', 'name' : 'tags' }),
    'tmt_awal'                  : forms.TextInput({'class' : 'form-control',  'placeholder' : 'TMT Awal', 'type' : 'date'}),
    'tmt_akhir'                 : forms.TextInput({'class' : 'form-control',  'placeholder' : 'TMT Akhir', 'type' : 'date'}),
    'judul_penelitian'          : forms.Textarea({'class' : 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'Judul Penelitian', 'rows':3, 'cols':20}),
}
```

**after**

```
widgets = {
    'anggota'                   : Select2MultipleWidget({'class' : 'form-control select2-multi', 'multiple' : 'multiple', 'name' : 'tags' }),
    'tmt_awal'                  : forms.TextInput({'class' : 'form-control',  'placeholder' : 'TMT Awal', 'type' : 'date'}),
    'tmt_akhir'                 : forms.TextInput({'class' : 'form-control',  'placeholder' : 'TMT Akhir', 'type' : 'date'}),
    'judul_penelitian'          : forms.Textarea({'class' : 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'Judul Penelitian', 'rows':3, 'cols':20}),
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).